# setText not working in while loop

Tags: java, android, android-layout

My app gets traffic updates from an API (this works) and returns a JSON array, which i'm then taking each element of in a while loop (JSONobject) and attempting to update a TextView with each result every 5 seconds.

However, my script is waiting 15 seconds and then updating to the last value. I've done some research and it says to use asynctask, which I have done, but it has not made a difference.

I've added `System.out.println(thestring_to_update_to)`, and this is working as I would like my app to do (changing every 5 seconds).

The following is in a try/catch block :

```
JSONArray TrafficInformation = new JSONArray(response);

int TrafficEvents = TrafficInformation.length();
int TrafficEvent = 0;

JSONObject CurrentEvent = new JSONObject();

do{
    CurrentEvent = new JSONObject(TrafficInformation.getString(TrafficEvent));

    TextView affected_route = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.disrupted_route);

    try {
        Object[] passTo = new Object[1];
        passTo[0] = CurrentEvent.getString("9");

        System.out.println(passTo[0]);

        new tasker().doInBackground(passTo);

        TrafficEvent++;
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(LiftShare.this, "There was an error with getting traffic info.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
} while (TrafficEvent < TrafficEvents);
```

I also have this public class

```
public class tasker extends AsyncTask {
    @Override
    protected Object[] doInBackground(Object[] Objects) {
        TextView affected_route = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.disrupted_route);
        affected_route.setText(Objects[0].toString());

        return null;
    };
}
```

this is the JSONArray that goes in to the code (It is formatted correctly)

```
Array
(
    [0] => {"1":"Congestion","2":"Minor Disruption - up to 15 minutes delay","3":"Location : The M3 eastbound exit slip at junction J9 . \nReason : Congestion. \nStatus : Currently Active. \nReturn To Normal : Normal traffic conditions are expected between 11:30 and 11:45 on 25 January 2018. \nDelay : There are currently delays of 10 minutes against expected traffic. \n","7":"M3 J9 eastbound exit | Eastbound | Congestion","9":"M3","10":"South East","11":"Hampshire","14":"2018-01-25T11:22:38+00:00"}
    [1] => {"1":"Overturned Vehicle","2":"Severe Disruption - in excess of 3 hours delay or road closure","3":"Location : The M3 westbound between junctions J8  and J9 . \nReason : Clearing the scene of an overturned vehicle. \nStatus : Currently Active. \nTime To Clear : The event is expected to clear between 14:45 and 15:00 on 25 January 2018. \nReturn To Normal : Normal traffic conditions are expected between 14:45 and 15:00 on 25 January 2018. \nLanes Closed : All lanes are closed. \nPrevious Reason : Following an earlier accident. \n","7":"M3 westbound between J8 and J9 | Westbound | Overturned Vehicle","9":"M3","10":"South East","11":"Hampshire","14":"2018-01-25T06:51:12+00:00"}
    [2] => {"1":"Congestion","2":"Moderate Disruption - between 15 minutes and 3 hours delay","3":"Location : The A34 southbound between the A272  and the junction with the M3 . \nReason : Congestion. \nStatus : Currently Active. \nReturn To Normal : Normal traffic conditions are expected between 12:45 and 13:00 on 25 January 2018. \nDelay : There are currently delays of 40 minutes against expected traffic. \n","7":"A34 southbound within the A272 junction | Southbound | Congestion","9":"A34","10":"South East","11":"Hampshire","14":"2018-01-25T07:48:23+00:00"}
)
```

How can I get the textview to update to the new value every 5 seconds?

Comment: Where is the Traffic information code running at? Is this a background thread? If so, who starts it and when?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use

```
new tasker().execute(passTo);
```

to start `asynctask` as a thread otherwise, with current implementation, it will just act as a normal method call

**Note:** you cannot update UI from background thread i.e. inside `doInBackground`, instead override `onPostExecute` which runs on UI thread

```
@Override
protected Object[] doInBackground(Object[] Objects) {
    TextView affected_route = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.disrupted_route);
    //affected_route.setText(Objects[0].toString()); crash, instead do this in onPostExecute

    return null;
};
```

Update : you can use `postDelayed` with delay to update UI after some interval

```
int i = 0;
affected_route.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        textView.setText(yourText);
    }
},i+=5000);
```

Comment: Thanks for edit, I was just about to comment the UI error, will try again.

Comment: How do I go about doing an on post execute?

Comment: @HarveyFletcher by doing this `Thread.sleep(5000);` you are adding a delay in main thread

Comment: I think there is no requirement of `asynctask ` it's achieved easily without `asynctask `  am i right @Pavneet_Singh ?

Comment: [**Override postexecute**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) , @Munir OP wants to update UI, apparently the optimal option to me is handler with runonui

Comment: I don't understand what I am supposed to do. I put the `affected_route.setText(passTo[0].toString());` back before the 5 second delay, but now I am getting the same problem that only the last string is shown after 15 seconds.

Comment: @HarveyFletcher seems like you are always fetch the same value here `CurrentEvent.getString("9");` you should be using some int variable by incrementing it in every iteration of loop

Comment: No, the value changes each time. `CurrentEvent = new JSONObject(TrafficInformation.getString(TrafficEvent));` and also `TrafficEvent++;`  "9" is the name of the field in the json array, which is different each time

Comment: @HarveyFletcher ok, then use the `postDelayed` method to update view with some delay and also don't do `findViewById` in loop , do it before loop

Comment: No this is not working. It still only shows the last one after 15 seconds. I want to show 1, then wait 5 seconds, then the next one, wait another 5, and then the third.

Comment: @HarveyFletcher oh got it, issue is loop is working normally and starting 3 thread almost at the same time so to get the the desired output , the next task should be started once the first is finish or you have to use the delay like 5 for first then 10 for second and then 15 for third

Comment: No, the problem is that the TextView is not updating at all until the while loop is complete. I know this because I can see the terminal output which is doing it right, but the UI is not updating until the while loop is done.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the updated postdelay has fixed it.

Comment: @HarveyFletcher i am glad that i could help, happy coding

Answer (score 1):

`AsyncTask` seems like a overkill for your requirement as you are not really doing any work in the background. You could schedule the text to be updated after a time period using a `Handler` (from `android.os`) like this:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    Runnable textUpdater = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // this needs to execute in the UI thread
            affected_route.setText(lastUpdate);
        }
    };
    String lastUpdate = "Store your last update here";

    void updateText(){
        handler.postDelayed(textUpdater, 5000);
    }
```